# Printing Label in windows form application

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows form application. In this application I am using one panel which contains many labels. They are having property of drag and drop. The user will drag and drop the labels where he want. 
Finally when he click on print button then it has to print.

But I am using list of labels.I am getting blank sheet.

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender,
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Label> lbls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
            foreach (var lbl in lbls)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl.Text,
             new Font(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), Int32.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()), FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, lbl.Left, lbl.Top);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems you might have.

First, set a breakpoint and check that `this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList()` actually has any items in it. If it doesn't then you may have to change it to look for child controls of the panel, not of the form.

Secondly, the page you're printing has a different size to your form, and it has margins. `PrintPageEventArgs.MarginBounds` will tell you where and how big the margins are. `PrintPageEventArgs.PageBounds` will tell you how big the page is. Make sure you draw inside the margins. If something is drawn outside the margins it probably won't get printed. If it's outside of the page then it's 100% definitely not getting printed.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion .I will try in both the ways

Comment: List<Label> labelList = new List<Label>();
            foreach (Control element in this.Controls)
           {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(element.Text,
            new Font(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), Int32.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()), FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, element.Left, element.Top);
            }

Comment: i have used above code. this will add all the labels to the list which are outside the panel. But i want to add labels which are inside the panel